# Error al iniciar un service

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, android-intent, android-service

Estoy intento crear un service el cual después de que el usuario haya dado una lista de nombres y un tiempo, un proceso se vaya ejecutando cada X tiempo dado por el usuario, aunque este haya cerrado la aplicación. Por lo que he estado buscando el service debería iniciarse pero no lo hace, simplemente cuando cambia a esa activity se cierra la aplicación por mal funcionamiento.

Muchas gracias.

```
//Clase create_time que permite preguntarle al usuario los segundo cada cuando se va a ejecutar un proceso
     public void battleFinal(View view){
            Intent battleFinal = new Intent(this, disputa_nombres.class);
            battleFinal.putExtra("lista",itemList);
            battleFinal.putExtra("segundos",secTotal);
            startService(battleFinal);
            startActivity(battleFinal);
        }


 // La clase disputa_nombres que permite de un arraylist de nombres ir eliminando aleatoriamente nombres y simular combates
 //   @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    int firstNum;
    int secNum;
    while (itemList.size() > 1) {
        try {
            //  TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(8);
            Thread.sleep(5000);  //La idea es que seas horas pero puse 5 seg para probar 

            pruebaText.setText(String.valueOf( itemList.size()));
            // createNotificationChannel();

        }catch (InterruptedException e){}
       
        firstNum = (int) (Math.random() * itemList.size());
        do{
            secNum = (int) (Math.random() * itemList.size());
        }while(secNum == firstNum);
          sendNotification(String.valueOf(firstNum));

        pruebaText.setText(itemList.get(secNum) + " ha peleado con "+itemList.get(firstNum));
        itemList.remove(firstNum);
        if(itemList.size() == 1){
            pruebaText.setText("Ha ganado "+itemList.get(0));
        }
       // sendNotification("Hola"); Prueba de que funcionen las notificaciones

    
    }
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Parece que este es error principal pero no lo entiendo

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service 
com.example.newapp.disputa_nombres: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.example.newapp.disputa_nombres cannot be cast to android.app.Service
```

Comment: Es importante revisar en el LogCat cual es el error que se muesta, revisa donde diga "Caused by"-

Comment: Parece que este es error principal pero no lo entiendo
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.newapp.disputa_nombres: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.newapp.disputa_nombres cannot be cast to android.app.Service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a el error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.newapp.disputa_nombres: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.newapp.disputa_nombres cannot be cast to android.app.Service

El problema es que cuando realizas un `Intent` tratas de abrir la clase `disputa_nombres` como servicio, pero esta clase no extiende de servicio si no seguramente de Activity, comenta esta linea para evitar este problema:

```
   public void battleFinal(View view){
            Intent battleFinal = new Intent(this, disputa_nombres.class);
            battleFinal.putExtra("lista",itemList);
            battleFinal.putExtra("segundos",secTotal);
            //*error:  startService(battleFinal);
            startActivity(battleFinal);
        }
```

Comment: El error así desaparece pero como inicio ahora el servicio, eso es lo que no estoy entendiendo. Muchas gracias

Comment: @MiguelGonzález el Servicio se inicia con  startService(....); ( no con startActivity(...) ) pero la clase que defines a iniciar debe extender de Service.